# Magento 2 - Install category attribute not work

Tags: magento2, php, category, eav, category-attribute

I created a custom form for creating some attributes for the category.
My code is this but it doesn't work:

InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Create\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
 
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;
 
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
         $installer->startSetup();
 
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'my_attribute',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Title my attribute',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 100,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => 'General Information',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );
$installer->endSetup();
    }
}
?>
```

and this is my category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="my_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title my attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>    
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The following has been tested on Magento 2.3.4 and 2.4.0

app/code/Create/Attribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="my_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Title my attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

app/code/Create/Attribute/Setup/Patch/Data/AddMyAttributeCategoryAttribute.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Create\Attribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddMyAttributeCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'my_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Title my attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}
```